# How to know if your breathing is normal?

Tags: human-biology, breathing

Is it possible for a device to measure how much air we breathe in and out over the entire day and at what rate? I think if we have access to this data we can compare it across people.

Comment: it is certainly possible to make. might be clumsy to wear though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a spirometer. There are different types of spirometers serving different purposes like the Incentive spirometer and the peak flow meter. I would suggest that you go through the [wikipedia page on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirometer) to get more info.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but then the most advanced spirometer seems to measure breathing only temporarily and not on-the-go i.e. complete day analysis when doing routine tasks. so i guess the state-of-the-art has not reached that level.

Comment: @user13107 Might be in development if the need arose but I am unaware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is [K4 device](http://www.serinth.gr/en/products/ergospirometers/portable-ergospirometers/cosmed-k4b2.html) and [K4 device](http://www.cosmed.com/en/products/cardio-pulmonary-exercise-testing/k4-b2-mobile-cpet). Beyond spirometry it can measure other variables such as:

- Pulmonary Gas Exchange (VO2, VCO2)
- Breath by Breath Technology
- Telemetry Data Transmission up to 1000m
- Indirect Calorimetry
- Integrated GPS System
- Integrated Oxygen Saturation (SpO2)
- Integrated 12-lead Stress Testing ECG